# Merge Multiple Data Frames with Different Feature Sets

Tags: r, dataframe, import-from-csv

I tried searching and found similar-ish problems, but not the same problem. This seems like this should be somewhat common so I probably am just missing it.

I have multiple CSV files I am reading in with read.table.  I want to merge these together such that rows with the same ID column are cbind() together, and the rest are left blank.  An example below probably better illustrates

File 1

```
UserID    val1     val2    
  1                  2
  2        1         3
```

File 2

```
UserID    col1  
  1         a
  3         z
```

File 3

```
UserID    feat1    feat2
  1        Hi       Hello
  3        Moshi    Moshi
```

Desired Result

```
UserID      val1      val2    col1     feat1    feat2
1                      2        a       Hi       Hello
2            1         3
3                               z       Moshi    Moshi
```

I don't want it to add zeroes for missing values. I don't want it to fill anything with NAs, if possible.

I just want to combine datasets (3+ in all cases, average of 10) on a UserID column, keeping everything else the same.

I'm sure there is a tool for this, I just can't find it.

Comment: you can use reduce:
`df = Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), list(file_1, file_2, file_3))`

as for fill value merging, easiest way i can think of is to do:
`df[is.na(df)] = ''`

this assumes that all `NA` values are treated the same in the dataset. otherwise you'll have to code different `NA`s witihn each dataframe not to lose information.

Comment: The correct way to do this will result in `NA` in non-matching positions. That's the correct value to place there. If you want something else, you'll need a second step to replace them. But it's sort of nonsensical to require they all be replaced with the same value if you have a mix of character/numeric columns. So you're better off sticking with NA.

Answer (score -1):

The merge function sounds right for this.

```
merged_df <- merge(df1, df2, by="UserID")
```

You can then apply this iteratively, e.g.

```
for(i in 2:number_data_frames){
  merged_df <- merge(merged_df, list_of_dfs[[i]], by="UserID")
}
```